# Creating a function of three variables from experimental data

Tags: regression

I have been working in a project in which I have to collect the following data over a timespan:

1. Temperature of a room
2. Humidity inside the room
3. Amount of CO2 present in the room
4. Number of persons in the room

I have already conducted the experiment and have built a datasheet having data of CO2 ($C$) , Temperature ($T$), Humidity ($H$), and number of persons ($S$).
Now, from the datasheet we have to create a function $f$ such that $C=f(S,T,H)$.
And I am not getting how to do it.
Can I get a solution to my problem?

Comment: There are infinite ways of doing this. Do you have any idea how the CO2 is affected by the measured parameters? Is it linear? Do the variables interact?

Answer (score 1):

You can use linear regression for your problem. Simply you need to form a function that

$$y = a_0 + a_1 \cdot x_1 + a_2 \cdot x_2 + a_3 \cdot x_3 $$

where $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ are what you need to find, while $y$, $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ are $C$, $S$, $T$, $H$ respectively.

You can use Matlab, R, Python to find the best values of $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$.

Answer (score 0):

If the model is supposed to be linear wtih respect to each of the variables $S,T,H$, it will write
$$C=a_0+a_1\,S+a_2\,T+a_3\, H+a_4\,ST+a_5\,SH+a_6\,TH+a_7\,STH$$ and you just face a simple multilinear regression problem.